How do I install Maple using WSL
I have a license for Maple, and am using it on Windows. However, a package that I need does not have a Windows version, only Linux. I have WSL installed but am not sure if it is even possible to run Maple through WSL, thus allowing me to install packages programmed for Linux only. For those interested, the package I am attempting to use is the FGb package found at "https://www-polsys.lip6.fr/~jcf/FGb/index.html" and I am using WSL2, and running Ubuntu version 22.04.1
If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated, and if there is anything else you need to know to help I will see what I can do to provide the information.

Please run regular Ubuntu in a VM instead. Complex and heavy applications like Maple may not work well with WSL
